# How do I scan a string for numbers, and convert the numbers to an integer form which I can access?

Tags: c

For instance, if a character array contains "86*20/20/(10)" I wish to be able to keep 86 in an int variable which I can manipulate I do not want to just count the number of numbers, I need the whole number as itself too. Also, is it possible to take the whole array and do "-'0'" to convert the whole thing to a number?

```
int is_operand(char item)
{
  if (item != '(' && item != ')' && item != '+' && item != '-' && item != '/' && item != '*' && item != '%')
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else  
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

void expressionQ(char *infix, Queue* qPtr)
{
// Write your code here
    // this is used to iterate the list
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int num;
  char num2;
  char* result;
  printf("This %c\n", infix[0]);
  num = infix[0] - '0';
  printf("testingHERE %d", num);
//   while (infix[i] != '\0')
//   {
//     if (is_operand(infix[i]))
//     {
//       num = infix[i];
//       i++;
//       // while (is_operand(infix[i]))
//       // {
//       //   num2 = infix[i];
//       //   result = malloc(strlen(&num) + strlen(&num2)+1);
//       //   strcpy(result, &num);
//       //   strcat(result, &num2);
//       //   i++;

        
        
//       }
//     }
//     i++;
//   }
//   // printf("Tests %c\n", result[0]);
// }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you have the code pattern `if (condition) { return 1; /* or true */ } else { return 0; /* or false */ }` then that's exactly equal to `return condition;`.

Comment: [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Or [strtok](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) followed by [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh okay thanks !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude isnt operand = any numbers? And is_operand just means that as long as it is not an operator, it is an operand?

Comment: @kaylum I looked up strtol and I think it converts all numbers to number if im not wrong? Is there a way such that I can convert only what I read per character, because I need to store separate integer values inside a linked list node which I didnt post in this qn because I dont think its nice to post my whole work here

Comment: `strtol()` tells you where it stopped converting; you can use that iteratively in a loop, skipping things that can't be a part of a number before trying again.  What numbers do you want out of a string such as `86/2022-02-04`?  4 positive numbers or 2 positive numbers and 2 negative numbers?  I don't need to know; you do.

Comment: I already mentioned `strtok`. That allows you to break the string up so that you can call `strtol` on each number.

Comment: @sasaasasasha Oh yeah! Misread that! Sorry... :)

Comment: @kaylum ahhh I see, thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Write some functions that *accept* (or *expect*) a specific valid input.

```
void skip_whitespace( char ** s )
{
  while (**s and isspace( **s )) *s += 1;
}

bool accept_operator( char desired_operator, char ** s )
{
  skip_whitespace( s );
  if (*s == desired_operator)
  {
    *s += 1;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int expect_number( char ** s )
{
  // success only if NON-whitespace was scanned,
  // so let us get rid of any leading whitespace ourselves
  char * first_non_ws = *s;
  skip_whitespace( &first_non_ws );

  // now we can try to extract a number
  int result = strtol( first_non_ws, s, 10 );
  if (first_non_ws == *s)
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Expected a number at \"%s\"\n", *s );
    halt( 1 );
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can then get information by asking for it:

```
char s[1000] = "12 * 3";

char * p = s;
int n1 = expect_number( &p );  // extracts '12'
if (accept_operator( '*', &p )) ... // successfully extracts '*'
```

Your next problem will be properly handling the operators. You should google around “recursive descent parser”. Here is a freebie for add/subtract:

```
int term( char ** s )
{
  int lhs = factor( s );
  while (true)
  {
    if      (accept_operator( '+', s )) lhs += factor( s );
    else if (accept_operator( '-', s )) lhs -= factor( s );
    else break;
  }
  return lhs;
}
```

Unless you are doing something with lower operator precedence than addition, that should be the first thing your expression() function calls.

```
int expression( char ** s )
{
  return term( s );
}
```

And the last thing should be parentheses, which should either:

- accept an open parenthesis, call expression(), and accept a close parenthesis, or
- expect a number

Now you can parse stuff in your code easily enough:

```
char s[1000] = "86*20/20/(10)";
char * p = s;
int result = expression( &p );

// if it matters, check to make sure there isn’t any other input left unread
skip_whitespace( &p );
if (*p)
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Expression not properly terminated!\n" );
  halt( 1 );
}
```

***Recursive Descent*** isn’t the only way to do this stuff, but it is the most direct.

The other good way to handle infix expressions is using ***Shunting Yard***. That, however, requires a bit more setup and post-processing.

- You must first properly *tokenize* things into an array/list/whatever
  <sup>Tokenization is identifying and storing objects</sup>
- You must pre-verify that the infix expression is properly-formed
  <sup>Because SY is *terrible* at validation</sup>
- You must afterwards compute the result!
  <sup>SY is an infix→postfix (RPN) converter. It doesn’t actually process the RPN expression.</sup>

Both RD and SY are very, very easy, but I suspect you are just trying to get through a simple homework assignment, and RD is really just the easier path for you, methinks.